# iframe tag doesn't work in IE

Tags: iframe

I have problem with ie

my code is

```
<div style="text-align: right"><iframe style="height: 900px; width: 720px" src="mypage.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe></div>
```

it's work in chrome,Firefox, ie 10 but doesn't work in ie6,7,8,9

please help me

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"? What are you expecting, and what is actually happening?

You may want to try specifying the `width` and `height` attributes, that is, in addition or instead of in the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear on what error you are getting but I used the following code to make a quick IFrame and it runs in IE version 7,8,9,10.

```
<div style="text-align: right">
        <iframe src="your page you want to reference" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="900px" width="720px" seamless="">
        </iframe>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.